# How to validate dynamic form fields using jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Still is not clear to me how I can validate a dynamic form fields using jQuery validate ()

Suppose I have a form like the following:

```
<form id="myform" action="" ...>
   <input type="text" form-control" name="cauthor[]" id="cauthor1" value=""/>
....

  <button type="button" class="clone btn btn-primary" value="Add">
 ....
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
...
</form>
```

As you can see I have a dynamic field (cauthor[]); So user can hit the Add button to create a new input field. Then after hitting the Add button my form will look like this:

```
   <input type="text" form-control" name="cauthor[]" id="cauthor1" value=""/>
   <input type="text" form-control" name="cauthor[]" id="cauthor1" value=""/>
   <input type="text" form-control" name="cauthor[]" id="cauthor1" value=""/>
```

Now the question is? How to validate all the fields?

```
$("#casos_clinicos_form").validate({
    rules: {
        'cauthor[]': {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'cauthor[]': "Author name not informed! Please correct and try again."
    }

});
```

It only validates the first one.

If you know how to handle the above, please reply.

Comment: You can assign a class to these controls then validation will work

Comment: @RashidJaved, absolutely wrong.  This plugin mandates that all input nodes contain a unique `name`.  Using your approach, only the first instance will be validated.  http://jsfiddle.net/mcqb2vk2/

Answer (score -2):

You can assign a class to input and then validate it.

```
Query.validator.addClassRules('myClassName', {
        required: true /*,
        other rules */
    });
```

Comment: Even after fixing your `Query` syntax error, your answer is broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/mcqb2vk2/

Comment: Wow! It's hard to believe no one knows how to handle this! Will post it into another site.